# Excel VBA: inserting WHEN formula into specific range of cells with variable changing column

Tags: excel, vba, macros, formula

Hello dear StackOverflow users,

My issue is regarding inserting a Formular via Macro into specific range of cells. Again, again and again.

So the Basic function of the formula should be the following:

`=WHEN('ZEK '!F3="X";"6";WHEN('ZEK '!G3="X";"8";"1"))`

In my macro it has to Change the column for the next specific range.
This is Happening in a for Loop for `i` growing.

meaning --> `=When('ZEK '!$F$"& i+2 &".......`
or in any other Syntax that should work. My try fairly does not, thats why I need your help.

This is my Initial try where i exchanged literally everything with strings:

```
Sub 123()
Dim a,b,c As String
a = 1
b = 6
c = 8

....

'used and declared variables k, x, f, a, b, c

Range(Cells(k + 2, 5), Cells(k + 27, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=WHEN('ZEK'!$F$" & f & "=" & x & ";" & a & ";WHEN('ZEK'!$G$" & f & "=" & x & ";" & b & ";" & c & "))"

End Sub
```

With that i get Runtime Error 1004. (changed it to .Formula from .FormulaR1C1)

I hope i gave enough Information, so that you could help me.
This really does not have to be performant, i just Need to get the formula into about 100.000 cells with `i` changing for each Range of cells

Comment: Did you try to put it in a loop? Is `f` the loop variable? Do you receive an error? If so, what is it? Change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula` if you want to use `A1` reference style.

Comment: I am Looping on `i`. f is the variable `f = i + 2`- in which i is always growing. With changing to .Formula i still get Runtime Error 1004.

Comment: Are you missing double quotes in your x,a,b,c variables? Instead of setting a formula, can you do `Debug.Print "=WHEN..."` to see if the formula is correctly written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a language problem... Try

```
"=IF('ZEK'!$F$" & f & "=" & x & "," & a & ",IF('ZEK'!$G$" & f & "=" & x & "," & b & "," & c & "))"
```

Notice the use of `IF` and `,` as a delimiter instead of `;`. Is `WHEN` even a valid worksheet function? To be honest I don't know if the worksheet functions get translated or not when setting the formula via VBA. The delimiters are adapted though.

edit: there is also the `.FormulaLocal` property that should work with `;` as delimiter! So change `.Formula` to `.FormulaLocal`. This will probably cause an error if you execute it on a machine that uses `,` as default delimiter so I'd try to stick with `.Formula`.

Comment: Hello arcadeprecinct,
I think we are almost at it. At least he does fill in the following formula into the right cell.
`=WENN(ZEK!$F$3=X;6;WENN(ZEK!$G$3=X;8;1))` WENN is the IF function in german.

Though he wants me to open a file and does not Redirect to the Sheet 'ZEK'. also the `' .. ' ` go missing.

Greetings TiroX

Comment: @TiRoX the `'...'` disappear because the sheet name doesn't contain spaces. Excel apparently can't find a sheet called "ZEK". Are you sure it is there (it has to be the name that is displayed in the tabs in the main window). If ZEK is the identifier and not the name (`(Name)` property instead of `Name` property in the VBA editor), use the name or `"..." & ZEK.Name & "..."`

Comment: Hello Arcadeprecinct,
I think we are almost done :D I just Need to fix that instead of X it is "X" in the Formular.
The current Output in german Excel:
`=WENN(ZEK!$F$3=X;6;WENN(ZEK!$G$3=X;8;1))`
The needed Output:
`=WENN(ZEK!$F$3="X";6;WENN(ZEK!$G$3="X";8;1))`
So I only Need to get behind, how i can Output "".

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @TiRoX Use *double* double quotes to get double quotes inside a string: `""X""`

Comment: I got it. 
My final formula: `"=IF(" & a & "" & f & "=""X""," & edi & ",IF(" & b & "" & f & "=""X""," & brofis & "," & druck & "))"`

Thank you a lot for the Support!!!