# Insert a formula into every cell with in a column that has red fill

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

[image]

I need the formula that is in the formula bar to be inserted ONLY into the cells that have red fill. I chose this method because I need the formula to be inserted into the column  (J) but only once per month... Then I need to get data from another table for another month.(I would adjust the vlookup formula to search through another table. Then, I would repeat the process and only insert THAT data for THAT particular month. If you have any advice for building a macro to do this please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far and let us know what the problem you encountered is?

Comment: I do not have any code so far, because I do not know how to set up this at all in VBA

Comment: Perhaps start with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38094487/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Have designed a template for you to assist.  [Here][1]/screenshots refer:

I present two methods - macro and macro-free (surprisingly quick btw - you may want to check it out too).

Before jumping into detail, I've scribbled some 'quick-start' steps...

### 1. Quick-start guide

***STEPS 1-3***

1. Copy / paste first VB module below (i.e. Insert_1) into a module within your VB project/workbook (ensure your workbook is macro-enabled e.g. filetype: .xlsb or .xlsm etc.)
2. Go to your workbook/worksheet, select an unused cell and ascribe the name `rng_fn`: often just requires typing this name into the window pane top left of your excel window/ beneath File command in ribbon:

[![Quick access to naming ranges - window pane, Excel][2]][2]

***Include your function in this cell***

3. Repeat step 2 for a different cell to give it the name 'rng_col' -

***Make this the same colour as the other cells that you want to insert the function from 3 above***

Once the function and colour have been specified / inserted in `rng_fn` and `rng_col` respectively, you'd good to go: simply run the Insert_1 macro and watch it come to life!

---

### 2. Macro method

![Linked Workbook with user output template[2]][3]

***DESCRIPTION***

This section comprises two macros:

1. *Insert_1* - performs what you requested: i.e. copies a function you specify in a specific cell into all cells with the same colour shading that you specify in another cell)
2. *Clear_1* - reverse of 1 (removes all content from any cell with corresponding colour shading)

***VB CODE***

```
Sub Insert_1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    calc_mode = Application.CalculationState

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Range("rng_fn").Activate
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("rng_col").Interior.ColorIndex
    
        
    Range("A1").Select

    Set Rng = Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    For Each cell In Rng
        cell.Select
        If cell.Address <> Range("rng_col").Address And cell.Address <> Range("rng_fn").Address Then
            If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("rng_col").Interior.ColorIndex Then
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        End If
        
    Next
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Application.Calculation = calc_mode

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub clear_1()

    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '...save current state for later...
    calc_mode = Application.CalculationState
    
    '...temporarily change to manual mode to speed up calcs/updates when running macro
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    

    'determines the colour based upon a named range within the workbook ('rng_col') and shall use this index to search entire worksheet for other cells that have the same / identical colour shading index...
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("rng_col").Interior.ColorIndex
    
        
    Range("A1").Select

    Set Rng = Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    For Each cell In Rng
        cell.Select
        'following will ensure that user input section remains in tact:
        If cell.Address <> Range("rng_col").Address And cell.Address <> Range("rng_fn").Address Then
            If Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = Range("rng_col").Interior.ColorIndex Then
                Selection.ClearContents

            End If
        End If
        
                                                                                                                                                                       Next
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'put calculation back to state prior to running code
    Application.Calculation = calc_mode

End Sub
```

---

### 3. Macro-free method

***STEPS 1-6***

1. Insert formula in any cell (not one of the shaded cells) and copy it to clipboard (i.e. simply select cell & press `Ctrl+C`) - in my case, I've entered `A5+A4` in cell B5 (modify formula by fixing cells with bullet '$' as required)
2. Select a contiguous group of cells that encompasses desired target cells (i.e. 'red shaded' in your case) per screenshot (yellow in mine:)

[![Step 2 - select contiguous cells that include target formatted cells][4]][4]

3. Ctrl + F to open find/replace dialogue box -> select 'Options' in 'Find' tab of this UI, select relevant format (red for you - yellow for me), specify 'Within sheet', other options (match case/by row or col, formula/value etc.) don't make a difference.

[![Step 3 - Find dialogue box][5]][5]

4. Select 'Find All' and select every entry that appears at bottom of this UI (i.e. from first/top, hold shift and press down arrow to select multiple)- or do in one go by selecting very top and pressing ctrl + shift + down.  *Satisfying feeling to see corresponding formatted cells in background become selected one after the other as you do this...*

[![Step 4 - select multiple cell references in UI][6]][6]

*Voila! Recall we have the function conveniently stored within our clipboard (step 1) - so simple matter of pasting the functions in which can be done simultaneously as follows:*

5. Close the find/replace UI window - your red formatted cells should still be selected (go back and follow steps 1-4 verbatim if not, go back and repeat steps exactly as they appear - something has gone wrong with this attempt).
6. Alt + E + S (i.e. paste special dialog/UI interface); select 'paste function' and press OK.

Done!

[![Step 6: paste formula from step 1 into all shaded cells simultaneously][7]][7]

֍

```
----------


  [1]: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9gYdZdhbDJhu2PeHK_g?e=fARbCY
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyevl.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjyzm.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmopx.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvlLv.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shcvw.png
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNdI2.png
```